# flash & Actionscript3 - passing objects to external swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Firstly Id like to say thanks to everyone who has helped me this week with some flash problems Iv had. Its been a great help.

Now to what I hope if my final problem

I have a object, called friends, It contains the url to facebook profile picture, ie

```
friends.friend1 = "http:// etc";
```

I have a swf file called, master.swf, which is passed the information to create the object through flashvars.

I need to get the object OR the flashvars info to the externally loaded swf, called pageOne.swf.

I have seen and tried several different methods, but now seem to give me what I need.

The important thing is that the pageOne.swf has access to the flashvars/object BEFORE it is rendered to the screen, as the info in the object/flashvars are used to construct it.

I am using the loader class to load the swf, castin it as a movieClip

Anyone have any ideas how to to the above?

CODE EXAMPLES:

master.swf

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
```

I need to either pass this to the pageOne.swf, OR make it available to it

How Im loading the external swf

```
function getFirstLevel()
    {
my_Loader = new Loader();
my_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading2);
my_Loader.load(new URLRequest("pageOne.swf"));

function finishLoading2(loadEvent:Event) {
    my_loadedSwf = loadEvent.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
    addChild(my_loadedSwf); 
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, my_loadedSwf.enterFrameHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,  my_loadedSwf.myOnPress);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, my_loadedSwf.myOnRelease);
    stage.focus = my_loadedSwf;

        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either append it to the url and then access it through LoaderInfo.parameters, or have both swf's share access to the same class definition and store it there.

The first example:

```
my_Loader.load(new URLRequest("pageOne.swf?friend1=..."));
```

Then, inside of pageOne.swf access it through loaderInfo.parameters:

```
this.loaderInfo.parameters.friend1
```

For the second case (and I actually prefer this one), in main.swf:

```
import shared.Model; // have a class which has a public static facebook url
                     // property, or have it be a Singleton with that property
                     // Obviously, the class name is only an example.
/* ... */

shared.Model.facebookURL = "..."
```

Then, in the loaded swf:

```
import shared.Model;
/* ... */
var url:String = shared.Model.facebookURL
```

Comment: In flash player 10.1+ I had to use a `LoaderContext` as this didn't work for me. Just something to keep in mind!